# Azure with OAuth 2 - google+ login information, and logout button

Tags: html, azure, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, azure-authentication

I'm new in programming and I have a question.

I try to use Azure with my simple HTML page to learn about Azure. I added authentication with Google with [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication)

It is worked good, but now I want to add login name (like: Hello @User), and log-out button into my page, but I don't know how to do that.

Can anyone help me with it?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What programing language do you want to use?

Comment: I using java and html with javascript.

Comment: If you got the answer, please mark an answer as correct (the green check image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google provides some client library for OAuth2 such as [google-oauth-java-client](https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client) and plenty of samples on [google-api-java-client-samples](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples).
If you want a step by step tutorial, you can use this: [OAuth 2.0 clients in Java programming tutorial series](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/security/library/se-oauthjavapt1/index.html)